# How to split every arc in a shapefile exactly in half?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, splitting, osgeo4w

I have a line shapefile containing several thousand arcs of varying length, representing a road system.  I need to split each arc exactly in half along it's length.  The resulting output would thus have two arcs of equal length for every input arc.  I have ArcGIS 10.4 and the OSGEO4W64 suite available.

The Arc Split command in the editor menu only works with one arc at a time, which would be too time consuming.  The Grass tools v.split.vert and v.split.length do not split each arc in half.

Comment: Calculate centroids using add geometry attributes. Convert xy to points. Split by points

Comment: what ArcGIS license level do you have (Basic, Standard, Advanced)? Do you have any Python development skills?

Comment: Have you looked at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25368/splitting-lines-automatically-at-specific-distances-using-arcgis-desktop?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101472/split-line-at-a-point-with-arcgis-10-1-basic-level-license may be worth looking at too

Answer (score 3):

This sequence in Arc 10.4 worked:

1. Feature Vertices to Points tool, applied to the input layer, with the "mid" option

followed by:

2. Split Line at Point tool, again applied to the input layer, using the point output from above.

One thing to note: the output Shapelength field needs to have its geometry recalculated because it contains the original layer's length.  This seems like a bug.

Thanks to all for their quick responses.

Comment: Note that Feature Vertices to Points requires an Advanced license